# How can I standardize icon size in Finder and across OS X 10.6.8 Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, snow-leopard, finder, icon

I running OS X 10.6.8 on a Mid-2009 MacBook Pro. I would like to standardize the size of icons seen in Finder (I use Icon View). Currently, every folder has its own icon size, which makes it less comfortable to use. I am tired of trying to "guesstimate" using the icon slider. Ideally, I would like to either revert all folders to default sizing, or be able to specify, for example, 48px.

I would also like to, if possible, revert the dock to default icon size (or at least be able to specify by pixel, and desktop icons also.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can change the default size in the view options panel:

[image]

The sizes of icons are also stored in .DS_Store files that override the default setting. You can delete them by running `sudo find / -name .DS_Store -delete`, but it also [resets other display options and removes Spotlight comments](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69467/consequences-of-deleting-ds-store/69722#69722). The changes aren't always picked up until you quit and reopen Finder.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to cover the "and across OS X 10.6.8 Snow Leopard?* part. How do I get the default icon size to change in open dialogs?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understood you correctly but:

By choosing **Show View Options** from the **View** menu, ( or just doing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> ) you can, precisely, specify the icon's size in pixels. And, if not in the desktop but in a folder, you can set this size as **default**.

[image]

Also, under `~/Library/Preferences` you can find the **Dock's** preferences. At the end of the file, you can find its size in pixels. Although I expected that editing the file and *reloggin* to do the trick, it, instead, created a new *preferences file*, so it was a lot easier just to change the value on the slider (under **System Preferences / Dock**) and checking its numerical value on the file.

[image]