# How can I sort my Download folder without having to do it manually every time

Tags: folders, sort

I want my download folder to be ordered in the following way:

Top left corner I want the last downloaded file and bottom right corner the oldest.

Right now, I always have to right-click inside my download folder and do the following:

Clean up by -> date created.

This is annoying - how can I have my download folder sorted in such way by default?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finder: keep sort-by per-directory](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89409/finder-keep-sort-by-per-directory)

Answer (score 1):

Use **Sort By** Date created rather than Clean up by.

Comment: Is there also a way to get it highlighted?

Comment: To get what highlighted? The newest file? No. Nothing simpler than just clicking on it.